# Read a pipe separated file on 32 bit machine

Tags: r, read.table

I have a pipe-separated file, which is too big to read in R using `read.table` on my 32-bit machine. There are certain rows where column 8 is blank and I can use that condition to filter out those rows. Is there any way I can filter those rows out while reading, so I don't have to load the whole file in memory?

Comment: `read.csv.sql` in the sqldf package can read a file into an SQLite database (which it creates on the fly) and then it reads only the data you specify in an sql statement into R.  Its only one line of code to do the whole thing.

Comment: You may parse it by hand using readLines() and strsplit() and decide which rows to keep. It would be simpler If you provided a small dummy file.